# How to force an org-babel session to reset or initialize?

Tags: org-babel, shell

If I run the following babel shell blocks

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session one :results output
  ssh staging
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session one :results output
  hostname
#+END_SRC
```

Org creates a shell buffer called `one`, runs `ssh staging` and then after connecting, executes `hostname` on staging. However, if I tweak the ssh command and run it again it attempts to run it from within session one, from the staging host. If I close the buffer `one` it resets the session as the next time any command is run with that session name it recreates it. What I haven't been able to find is a method to force a particular babel block to always initialize a new session.

I'm aware that for some languages (elisp in particular) this would not be possible. I suppose I could prepend the session with an elisp block containing `(kill-buffer "one")`, but would rather this was a header argument if possible. I'm also aware that for this example I could simply combine the two into a single block with no session, but I'm interested in more complicated sequences.

Is there a `:prologue` command or some other special argument to `:session` that forces that block to initialize a new shell on every invocation?

Comment: There is no such option (or a source code block parameter) in Org 8.2.10, but it should be pretty easy to add. I would start by hacking `org-babel-initiate-session`.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

Force an org-babel session to *reset or initialize* by using an [elisp conditional statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html) to dynamically set the value of the [:session](http://orgmode.org/manual/session.html) header on the first code block.

e.g. `:session  (if (get-buffer "one") (if (kill-buffer "one") (print "one") (print "one")) (print "one"))`

In the above code, [get-buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html) function checks if buffer named *one* exists. If true, the [kill-buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Buffers.html) function **kills** the *one* buffer then returns a value of `t` or `nil` which is passed to the [`if`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html) statement. In this specific example, the nested `if` statement will *always return a value of one*. Please note, I'm still learning elisp.

Below is the updated example code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session (if (get-buffer "one") (if (kill-buffer "one") (print "one") (print "one")) (print "one")) :results output
  ssh staging
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session one :results output
  hostname
#+END_SRC
```

Each time the first code block is executed, emacs will ask to kill the *one buffer*, so you can reset the session when you desire.

> **EDIT**
>
> **Oops** missed part that you *always* wanted buffer killed, i.e. [no prompting](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/disabling-prompts-emacs). Execute this block first to temporarily turn off prompting to kill buffer.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
  (setq kill-buffer-query-functions
    (remq 'process-kill-buffer-query-function
           kill-buffer-query-functions))
#+END_SRC
```

Hope that helped!

Note: This code was tested using the following versions of emacs and org-mode.

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-29-g89a0ac-elpa)
```

In conclusion, I found **technical inspiration** for this answer on the [org-scraps](https://eschulte.github.io/org-scraps/) website and this [kill-buffer example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365118/951721) on stackoverflow.

Comment: @dgtized did this answer help?

Comment: I wasn't aware you could embed elisp in the session call, so thank you for that. That said, as I mentioned in the original question, I was aware that I could automate `kill-buffer` to force a new session, but was more interested in learning if there was a block argument built into org-mode, or some other established convention for doing this that I was not aware of. Your approach is a nice work-around, but I'm hoping there is a canonical approach for this.

Comment: @dgtized - Are you looking for an answer like this? `:session one :session-reset yes`?

Comment: Something like that sure. Again, it's as much a question of what the recommended practice is for this example. Surely other people have sessions that need resetting, and if they just kill the buffer that's fine, but I want to know what the standard practice is.

Comment: @dgtized - Thanks for clarifying! This is great question! I have not found a documented standard practice but **I will keep looking**.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Melioratus.

Currently, org-babel provides a hook called `org-babel-after-execute-hook`. I extended the supported arguments of org-babel src block by using it:

(I'm using org-babel for elixir. If you want supports of other languages, extend `cond` by yourself.)

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'semacs/ob-args-ext-session-reset)

(defun semacs/ob-args-ext-session-reset()
  (let* ((src-block-info (org-babel-get-src-block-info 'light))
         (language (nth 0 src-block-info))
         (arguments (nth 2 src-block-info))
         (should-reset (member '(:session-reset . "yes") arguments))
         (session (cdr (assoc :session arguments)))
         (session-process
          (cond ((equal language "elixir") (format "*elixir-%s*" session))
                (t nil))))
    (if (and should-reset (get-process session-process))
        (kill-process session-process))))
```

After evaluating above code, you can write src block like this:

```
#+begin_src elixir :session-reset yes
  IO.puts("HELLO WORLD")
#+end_src
```

After evaluating src block, org-babel will cleanup the corresponding session.